# Django template tag if condition for URL

Tags: django, django-templates

I have variable to be validated in html template:
`{{ item.node.href }}`

```
{% if item.node.href is http or https %}
  Do some thing
{% else %}
  Do something else
{% endif %}
```

Can you help me to write up if condition for validating item.node.href if it contains **http://** or **https://** in the URL ?

Comment: Are you trying to perform diffrent action for **http://** and **https://** ?

Comment: Variable : ' item.node.href' -> may have value as '/django', '/mypage' OR 'https://youtube.com', 'https://google.com'
So i just need to display those 2 sets of URL differently in html  page based on if condition. I am new to Django :-)

Answer (score 1):

Testing substrings in Python is pretty easy:

```py
{% if 'http' in item.node.href or 'https' in item.node.href  %}
  Do some thing
{% else %}
  Do something else
{% endif %}
```

As `http` is also contained in `https`, it would be sufficient to do

```py
{% if 'http' in item.node.href  %}
  Do some thing
{% else %}
  Do something else
{% endif %}
```

(Of course, this assumes that `item.node.href` is the full url including potocol)

Comment: Awesome that helped me thanks @nechoj and Ankit